# XAMPP with an error message

Tags: file, xampp, directory

I have a problem that i cannot to resolve it.
    I think this is a XAMPP problem. 
    When i'm trying to open my website on localhost i have this message  :

```
No such file or directory
When i try to open another  on localhost it run without problem.
```

Can you say me what is the problem please ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are accessing the right resource from your uri Do the following

```
 In the file 
 \xampp\apache\conf\extra\httpd-xampp.conf
```

search for "LocationMatch".

Once you find it, make a change to the “Deny from all” to have a # in front of it.  See code below.

```
 <LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
 Order deny,allow
 #Deny from all
 Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8
 ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
```